# Nuxt how can I browse static file

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a php file under of static folder.
How can i browse the php file?

I tried to use a proxy on config, but its not working

```
/pages
/static
  test.php
```

How could i browse it

```
localhost:port/[proxy]/test.php
```

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by browse? see its content? Or see result of its execution?

Comment: Hi @Aldarund, both. 
the php file contains contents for display and execution.

Comment: For execution you need php server that will handle it. Nothing to do with vue or nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need a webserver to handle your .php file.
/static folder is for static content.

This is what i found in the documentation:

> If you don't want to use Webpack assets from the assets directory, you can create and use the static directory (in your project root folder).
>
> All included files will be automatically served by Nuxt and are
>   accessible through your project root URL. (static/favicon.ico will be
>   available at localhost:3000/favicon.ico)

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/#static

Comment: But what if we have files in static folder that we want to prevent direct access if the user has not logged in yet with Okta, will that be possible? How to address this scenario?